# Unwanted Excel Sheet protection

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

I am running into a recurring issue while working with Invantive Control. I am building a report with multiple Invantive formulas. As I need to access more administrations than my default, I select the administration I need and deselect the default one.

For some reason, after returning to the sheet, my workbook is protected again and I can't continue my work. I also would not know what password it is protected with. This means I have to copy my whole report to a blank sheet and work from there again. But it keeps happening and I don't know how to avoid it.

How can I disable the sheet protection with Invantive Control?

Answer (score 0):

For compliance with SAS-70 and ISO 2700[12], the work sheets are protected by default when you install a model. The model itself is protected very well, but the worksheets are only protected using default Excel protection with the known security risks.

## Option 1: unprotected with password

The password used to protect the sheet you can specify as "Password access" on the Model. See picture. You can use that password to make the work sheets editable again.

[image: Disable security protection]

## Option 2: remove protection altogether

Normally, the contents of the Excel work sheets are not editable. But when you specify blocks which allow insert/update/delete, the rows in these blocks are editable. Borders and all other contents is not editable.

You can also completely disable the protection using the checkbox "Allow changes outside blocks". See picture. Note that this might violate local information security policies.

## Option 3: make some cells editable

When you just need to be able to edit some cells, you might want to use the Protection tab of the Format Cells window of Excel: remove the check with "Locked" for those cells that you want to be able to edit, even with protection by Invantive Control in place.

[image: Disable cell protection]